# Longer time for SSL handshake in MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

Customer complains that our receiver channel is taking longer time for the SSL Handshake. **The MQ version is MQ7.1.0.6** and the OS is Solaris
This problem started to appear just since two weeks.

I check the http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=63615  URL on OCSP and not sure if I can set *OCSPCheckExtensions=NO* in qm.ini file. Could you please let me know if it is a good approach to set *OCSPCheckExtensions=NO*

Suggestions are most welcome

Comment: If you don't want/need OCSP checking, then what you say is the way to turn off said checking. You seem to already have all the answers to your question in the links you provide. Is there something you don't know that you are trying to ask?

Comment: @Morag Hughson: Please propose 3 other cases why the issue is happening now so that I can work in that direction.

Comment: Our issue is resolved after setting the disconnect interval of the sender channel to zero. No more SSL handshake delay.